# Find the number of integers n such that the equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the number of integers n such that the equation 
$xy^2+y^2-x-y=n$
has an infinite number of integer solutions $(x,y)$.

Comment: $N=-1$  is one such result (see: prime numbers)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ the same as $x$ and $y$ (respectively)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
n
&=xy^2+y^2-x-y\\
&=x(y^2-1)+y^2-y\\
&=x(y-1)(y+1)+y(y-1)\\
&=(y-1)(x(y+1)+y)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$y-1$ divides $n$.

If $n=0$,
$y=1$ and any $x$
is a solution,
so this does it.

If $n \ne 0$,
to get an infinite number of solutions
we must have
$y = -1$,
otherwise there are'only a finite number of solutions.
In this case,
$n
=(-2)(-1)
=2
$
for any $x$.

If $n \ne 0$
and $n \ne 2$,
there are only a finite number
of $y$ such $y-1$
divides $n$.

The only solutions are therefore
$(n, x, y)
=(0, x, 1)
,(2, x, -1)
$
for any $x$.